# Head tags displays inside body on CakePhp

Tags: php, html, cakephp, tags

I have a strange error on CakePhp 2.0 where the head tags renders empty, and all the tags that belongs to head, renders into the body before any content.

This his how the layout default.ctp looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <title>
        <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
    </title>
    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
        echo $this->Html->script(array('librerias/jquery.tools.min'));
        echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
        echo $this->Html->css('webfront');
        echo $scripts_for_layout;
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
(the rest of the html render)
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how it's rendered, as firebug says:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
&#65279;&#65279;
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title> Usuarios </title> **(IE moves the title tag on the head manually, it seems)**
    **(IE displays the DOCTYPE on its debugging console here)**
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/web/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/web/favicon.ico">
    <script src="/web/js/librerias/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    <link href="/web/css/cake.generic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/web/css/webfront.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"> </div>
        (the rest of the html render)
</body>
</html>
```

It's bad enough because it distorts the DOCTYPE tag and makes IE render the page very buggy.

Also, I have another test site where it doesn't happen this error. In fact I switched layouts and the error was the same.

Does someone knows why this happens? I couldn't find anything similar on the web and I don't have any clue about this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're likely looking at / editing the wrong file (or your saves aren't being uploaded).  It shouldn't be auto-creating a DOCTYPE for you.  I just tested - when I remove the DOCTYPE from my layout file, it's gone from the rendered page as well.

Comment: That can happen if debug info gets prepended to the top, or an error occurs somewhere within the PHP code that breaks the tags and HTML.

Comment: @Dave, I was editing de right file, as every other change I made to the layout was reflected on the render.

Comment: @jeremyharris, that could be, but cake log shows nothing but hard errors (for example, those that shows when trying to access a wrong page), and that were fixed. So it leaves me again without any clue :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally we got the answer for this problem. It was Cake's php and the infamous character &#65279 that appeared on utf-8 encoding. By changing every encoding on php files that passed before the final layout, we solved the problem.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you have file with BOM char . use BOM Detector program

java : http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=257 [recommended][find and remove]

1- check URL for exist BOM 
2- remove BOM from your file 
php : http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/04/detecting-utf-bom-byte-order-mark/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one end  tag in the layout file.

```
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
    (the rest of the html render)
    </body>
    </html>
```

It should be corrected as follows

```
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
    (the rest of the html render)
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It was already in the layout, but I may have it deleted by mistake when tried to abbreviate the code as "the rest of the html render".